# MPMoviePlayer crash in table cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to add a movie player in my cell.

Code:

```
- (MPMoviePlayerViewController*)setUp
{
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

//.. setting frame etc
//not starting the player; no fancy set up, everything default.

    return player;
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.tag = indexPath.row;

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^(void)
        {
            MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [self setUp];
            if (player)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                {
                    if (cell.tag == indexPath.row)
                    {
                        [cell.contentView addSubview:player.view];
                        [cell setNeedsLayout];
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

If I added it to only only cell, there is no problem, if I added it to more than one let say 10 or 20, I always get this crash.

Error:

> *** Assertion failure in -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification:], /SourceCache/MediaPlayer_Sim/MobileMusicPlayer-2526.83/SDK/MPMoviePlayerController.m:1351
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'movie player  has wrong activation state (1)'

Full trace:

> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x01dcf1e4
>   __exceptionPreprocess + 180
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0191c8e5 
>   objc_exception_throw + 44
>
> 2   CoreFoundation
>   0x01dcf048 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
>
> 3  Foundation                          0x014fc4de -[NSAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
>   4  MediaPlayer                         0x00017450
>   -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification:] + 235
>   5   Foundation                          0x015ef049 **57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 40
>
>   6  CoreFoundation                      0x01e2af04
>   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 20
>   7   CoreFoundation                      0x01d82efb _CFXNotificationPost +
>   2859
>   8   Foundation                          0x01528e41
>   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 98
>   9   MediaPlayer                         0x0001a085
>   -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 133
>   10  MediaPlayer                         0x00019ff1
>   -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _postNotificationName:object:] + 67
>   11  MediaPlayer                         0x000197b2
>   -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _ensureActive] + 199
>   12  MediaPlayer                         0x00014962 -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew prepareToPlay] + 85
>   13  MediaPlayer                         0x00012ccd
>   -[MPMoviePlayerController prepareToPlay] + 42
>   14  MediaPlayer                         0x00082c77 -[MPMoviePlayerViewController loadView] + 335
>   15  UIKit   0x006fb0d3 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 78
>   16  UIKit   0x006fb5d9 -[UIViewController view] + 35
>   17  MyTableView  0x0000381f -[MyTableViewTableViewController prepareStreams] + 159
>   18  MyTableView                   0x00004115
>   __72-[MyTableViewTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 53  19 libdispatch.dylib                   0x044c17b8
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
>   20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x044d64d0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
>   21  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x044c4eb7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 291
>   22  libdispatch.dylib    0x044c5127 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
>   23  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x04805dab _pthread_wqthread + 336
>   24  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x04809cce start_wqthread + 30 
>   ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I have tried all the solutions I could have found on SO, but none works. I am not even starting the player in the cells. Has been taking me for hours. Started out as a fun project that turned out to be headache. But I really like to know why and what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Include below two line inside main queue:-

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue,()^{

   MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [self 
    setUp];
        if (player)
        {
```

Comment: Thanks for response; care to explain why? It seems like it beats the purpose of using `async` if I put everything within main queue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do what you're doing - you're not recycling the movie player controller. The other answer here isn't going to solve your problem, it's just hiding it by making you run everything on the main queue.

Currently every time your app requests a cell, you create *a new MPMoviePlayerViewController* instance. This is bad because it defeats the purpose of a `UITableView`, which is to recycle its views. Instead, you should create a `UITableViewCell` subclass with a movie player controller inside of it. That way you only have to instantiate it once, and not every time the cell is scrolled onto the screen. Your current approach is really inefficient, and is going to result in all kinds of bad behavior.

The other thing you should probably look at is the class itself - you're using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, but that class is specifically designed to be presented as a view controller in full screen. If you're embedding it inside a table view cell you shouldn't use it. Instead, you should use `MPMoviePlayerController` and embed its view in your table view.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested here; I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` but it doesn't show any controls on the overlay, only a black screen while before there was a play button with `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. Thanks.